# Highlight only required field validation errors

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

In one of our projects we want to show the "Required field validation error" by changing the border color of the corresponding textbox. our page contains a lot of required field validator,regular expression validator etc. But we want to highlight only the required field errors.

Is there any way to do this without using any custom validation function.?
or Is there any method to find all the required field validators in a page in the client side. If we can find this i think we can highlight the corresponding error textbox

Answer (score 0):

one option, maybe less annoying than switching to custom validators, is to create your own javascript validation function that is triggered with a submit click. from here you can change the appearance of the invalid fields.